# Nancy model binding not working in Chrome, IE

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, nancy

I have been having this issue in one of my applications and have stripped it down and set up a small test environment in which the problem still occurs.

I am posting the following object (JSON)

```
{
    "eventName":"Testing from Services",
    "tickets":10,
    "_date":"10/10/2013",
    "_time":"8:00 PM",
    "ticketsLocation":"Testing from Services",
    "date":"2013-10-11T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

using the following ajax call

```
self.save = function (item, url, success) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        contentType: "application/json, charset=utf-8",
        traditional: true,
        datatype: "json",
        url: self.domain + url,
        success: success,
        error: self.error
    });
};
```

and then binding the data with the following code on the server

```
var Model = this.Bind<PropertyType>();
```

where `PropertyType` is the correct type (`Event`).

Here is the `Event` class for reference

```
public class Event
{
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public int Tickets { get; set; }
    public Venue Venue { get; set; }
    public string TicketsLocation { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<EventRequest> Requests { get; set; }
}
```

This works perfectly fine in Firefox. In Chrome and IE, `Model` ends up being an `Event` object with all null values. As far as I can tell (by using Fiddler), the post request is exactly the same between all browsers. I have also tested this on other machines, ruling out my machine and/or browsers as the issue.

Any ideas? I don't understand how the browser affects Nancy model binding...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simple answer is that your content-type is invalid. There is no such thing as an `application/json, charset=utf-8` content type, despite what people might tell you. Even though `charset` is a valid, optional, extension to content-type it does not apply to `application/json`

You can read about this here http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627 under section `6 IANA considerations`

> The MIME media type for JSON text is application/json.
>
> Type name: application
>
> Subtype name: json
>
> Required parameters: n/a
>
> **Optional parameters: n/a**

With the additional explanation about encoding

> Encoding considerations: 8bit if UTF-8; binary if UTF-16 or UTF-32
>
> ```
>  JSON may be represented using UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32.  When JSON
>  is written in UTF-8, JSON is 8bit compatible.  When JSON is
>  written in UTF-16 or UTF-32, the binary content-transfer-encoding
>  must be used.
> ```

In short, JSON is already, implicitly, `utf-8`. In fact, under section `3. Encoding` it states

> JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is UTF-8.

Send in `application/json` and you should be set to go

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was that. Thanks for your help.